# Frame on lstlisting opened on the bottom when code longer than one page

Tags: listings, page-breaking, framed

In my `\lstset` I have:

```
\lstset{
language=Java,                    % the language of the code
basicstyle=\sffamily\large,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
%numbers=left,                      % where to put the line-numbers
%numberstyle=\footnotesize,         % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
%stepnumber=1,                      % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line 
                                    % will be numbered
%numbersep=10pt,                      % how far the line-numbers are from the code
%backgroundcolor=\color{white},      % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
showspaces=false,                   % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,           % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                   % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
frame=single,                      % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,                        % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=t,                     % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,                  % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,           % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
%title=\lstname,                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
caption=grail.sablecc,             % also try caption instead of title
escapeinside={\%*}{*)},            % if you want to add a comment within your code
morekeywords={*,...}               % if you want to add more keywords to the set
}
```

taken from a wikibook. The problem is that when the source code is really long and requires 2 or more pages, I would like that the frame would close on every page instead of having the bottom of the listing open.
Is that possibile?

Comment: You would have to manually break the listing by only showing enough lines (using, say, `lastline=<n>)`. Then you can post the exact same listing on a subsequent page using a combination of `firstline=<n+1>,lastline=<m>`, etc. Browsing under the tag combination [`{listings}` and `{page-breaking}`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings+page-breaking) also provides some good ideas.

Comment: Such an open box indicates that the listing will continue on the next page. As alternative you could choose a colored background instead of the frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) documentation describes this on page 54. In summary, `listings` does not support such frames by itself. The [`framed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) package is recommended instead:

```
\usepackage{framed}

. . .

\begin{framed}
\begin{lstlisting}
%or \lstinputlisting{…}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{framed}
```

There is also a similar, newer [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package which might be of interest.

Comment: @Andrew: `mdframed` doesn't support this feature yet.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Nice to know but odd. Isn't `mdframed` itself a modification of `framed`?

Comment: it is but my motivation to write the package was the missing support of opened environment on page breaks. That is the difference.

Comment: This adds an ugly black border around the listing. Not what I wanted…